# Execute Windows Run Command or Some Windows Batch Process from Android

Tags: android, windows, batch-processing, remote-desktop

I want some information. Can we execute windows run command from android device? Like for example I want to open a file in PC using my android device such as Run>C:\abc.exe.

Or you can say I want to run a batch process (Exe File) placed in PC from my android device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Please use http://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.